# Stacked area chart each element on top of the previous

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code does show a stacked area chart where the two elements shown appear to be one on top of each other, not overlaping in y.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
theme_set(theme_bw())

df <- economics[, c("date", "psavert", "uempmed")]
df <- df[lubridate::year(df$date) %in% c(1967:1981), ]

# labels and breaks for X axis text
brks <- df$date[seq(1, length(df$date), 12)]
lbls <- lubridate::year(brks)

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=date)) + 
geom_area(aes(y=psavert+uempmed, fill="psavert")) + 
geom_area(aes(y=uempmed, fill="uempmed")) + 
labs(title="Area Chart of Returns Percentage", 
   subtitle="From Wide Data format", 
   caption="Source: Economics", 
   y="Returns %") +  # title and caption

scale_x_date(labels = lbls, breaks = brks) +  # change to monthly ticks and labels
scale_fill_manual(name="", 
                values = c("psavert"="#00ba38", "uempmed"="#f8766d")) +  # line color
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  # turn off minor grid
```

[image]

However this code requires to know beforehand the different elements used for fill, in this case psavert and uempmed. Is there any way of showing a dynamic group of elements stacked on top of each other without collision in y?

Comment: You just need to `melt` your `df`: `ggplot(reshape2::melt(df, "date"), aes(date, value, fill = variable)) + geom_area() + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00ba38", "#f8766d"))` There should be a duplicate for this somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` is intended for long-format data. We can use `tidyr::gather` to convert the data to long format, then the plotting is simplified and we can have arbitrarily many variables without changing the plot code:

```
df_long = tidyr::gather(df, "var", "value", -date)
head(df_long)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   date       var     value
#   <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 1967-07-01 psavert  12.5
# 2 1967-08-01 psavert  12.5
# 3 1967-09-01 psavert  11.7
# 4 1967-10-01 psavert  12.5
# 5 1967-11-01 psavert  12.5
# 6 1967-12-01 psavert  12.1
```

Notice we now have a single column for the `y` values, and a separate key column, `var`, distinguishing between the different variables. This means when we plot below we only need a single `geom_area` layer. If there were more than two variables in the `var` column, they would also be plotted just fine. The resulting plot is the same.

```
# plot
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = value, fill = var)) +
  labs(
    title = "Area Chart of Returns Percentage",
    subtitle = "From Wide Data format",
    caption = "Source: Economics",
    y = "Returns %"
  ) + 
  scale_x_date(labels = lbls, breaks = brks) +  # change to monthly ticks and labels
  scale_fill_manual(name="", 
                values = c("psavert"="#00ba38", "uempmed"="#f8766d")) +  # line color
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  # turn off minor grid
```

---

As a side-note, I'd recommend using code comments to (a) explain *why* you do things, and (b) document any unusual or tricky ways you do things. I think you'll find that more obvious comments like `# title and caption`
are pretty useless. The code line `title = "Area Chart of Returns Percentage"` is pretty clear by itself.